# C++ printing char array with string lib

Tags: c++

Say I have a char array: Char[3] which contains a,b,c.

What would be the easiest way to print Char as "abc" without using any of the c++ string libraries.

I am trying to overload the << operator so that i can print a class obj that contains a char array back as the original string that the obj was made with.

I am confused as to how to implement the solutions provided.

my word objs can be used like this:

Word.length() returns how long it is
Word[XXX] will return whats at index XXX

Comment: Does it have to not contain a null at the end of the array?

Comment: @chris nulls are string terminators.  No strings here.

Comment: @SethBattin, Char arrays in C and C++ are typically null-terminated. I took the string referred to as `std::string`.

Comment: @chris Regardless, this operation does not require them.  Although simonarame's implementation wisely checks for them anyway, since the objects are constructed from strings.  Which should, yes, contain null terminators.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

char data[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

std::copy(data, data + sizeof data, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class OverloadedCharArrayClass {
 public:
  char* chars;

 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const OverloadedCharArrayClass& charArray){
  int i=0;
  while(charArray.chars[i]!='\0'){
   os<<charArray.chars[i];
   i++;
  }
  return os;
 }
}
```